# Django Heroku app moved to new computer - error on git push heroku master

Tags: django, git, github, heroku

I recently moved my Django project deployed on Heroku to a new computer. By cloning my repository on my new computer. I have now made changes to the project on the new computer and have committed to my GitHub repository.

Now I have added my project GitHub repository, as well as the Heroku remote repository to the remote and I, can see it when I run `git remote -v`:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/username/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/repo.git (push)
```

Now when I want to commit new changes I do:

`git add .`

and then

`git commit -m "commit message"` - which commits to my GitHub repository? I do not know if this is correct

Now when I want to push to heroku master using the command `git push heroku master`
I get the following error:

```
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (fetch first)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I have also added keys, using `heroku keys:add` which since I didn't have any keys on my new computer I created a new one, which now I can see it when I run `heroku keys`.

I want to just push the new changes I made on my repository to heroku master. How can I push the new changes? using the command `git push heroku master`?

I have tried these command:

1. `git push heroku master -f`
   Which this gave me the error:  `! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`
2. `git push heroku +HEAD:master`

Which this gave me the error:  `! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

2. I have tried `git fetch` and I still get the same error

**EDIT**

I ran `git fetch heroku`, However, Now I get a new error:

```
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

I have tried using `git push -f heroku master` however, I get the error:
 `master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git pull
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push heroku master
```

Furthermore, check out [here](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-commit/) what `git commit -m "commit message" do.